# asp button onclick reloads the parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button and added onlcik event from the code behind. When I click on the button it reloads the parent page. What could be the problem? Please let me know.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReport" runat="server" Text="Report"/>
```

Code behind:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWin", 
    "<script language=javascript>function Report() { window.open ('" + 
    url + "', null,'top=1,left=1,center=yes,resizable=no,Width=840px,
    Height= 300px,status=no,titlebar=no;toolbar=no,
    menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes');}</script>");

btnReport.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "Report()");
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should actually use the `OnClientClick` attribute:

```
btnReport.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "Report()");
```

Comment: OnClientClick is not invoking the new window.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use LinkButton or Hyperlink?

Comment: you can use hyperlink. Just pass a parameter to the url when click occured. depending on the parameter do whatever